# Separar en dos partes separado por ',' string con Split en jquery

Tags: jquery, split

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$("#importenew").val(dataTable.row(this).data()[23]);
```

y se ve así: 1700,5

¿Es posible verlo así?:
1700 
5

He probado esto:

```
$("#liquidaredit").val(dataTable.row(this).data()[20]); 
var str1 = $("#liquidaredit").val(dataTable.row(this).data()[20]); 
var chunks = str1.split(",");
alert(chunks[0]); 
alert(chunks[1]);
```

Pero me dice que split no es una función.

¿Alguna solución?

Comment: tendrá un `.toString()` ?

Comment: ¿Que tipo de elemento es `#importenew`?

Answer (score 2):

En este apartado del código

```
var str1 = $("#liquidaredit").val(dataTable.row(this).data()[20]);
```

estas asignando el valor a el elemento con id `liquidaredit` pero no recoges el valor por tanto no puede tener una función `split` ya que esta devolviendo el propio elemento y no el valor interno que se ha asignado

Para solventar esto se podría hacer:

```
$("#liquidaredit").val(dataTable.row(this).data()[20]); // asigno el valor
const str1 = $("#liquidaredit").val(); // recojo el valor
var chunks = str1.split(",");
alert(chunks[0]); 
alert(chunks[1]);
```

Comment: Me sigue marcando TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Comment: haz un console.log de `str1` y de `$("#liquidaredit")` para corroborar que existen